# jquery sortable list accross different panes

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-ui-sortable, panes

Does anyone know how to get this [jquery sortable example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) to work accross different panes? ... meaning each sortable list is in a different pane.  I can't drag across the pane.  I'm using [ui layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) for my panes.

Thanks much!

Comment: panes you mean browser window ? if not, i think u need to use the 'connectWith' to put both together

Comment: If you look at ui layout you can see that they create different "panes".   At lease that is what they call them...  I need each list to be in it's separate "pane".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got it!  Wow, pretty tricky.

my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('body').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });

$("#sortable1").sortable({
    helper: function (e, ui) { return $(ui.get(0)).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();},
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function (e, ui) { alert("sort 1 recieved an item... update Database.") }
}).disableSelection();

$("#sortable2").sortable({
    helper: function (e, ui) { return $(ui.get(0)).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show(); },
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function (e, ui) { alert("sort 2 recieved an item... update Database.") }
}).disableSelection();

$("#sortable3").sortable({
    helper: function (e, ui) { return $(ui.get(0)).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show(); },
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function (e, ui) { alert("sort 3 recieved an item... update Database.") }
}).disableSelection();
```

});

HTML:

```
    <BODY>
<DIV class="ui-layout-center">
    <div>
        <div class="casted-and-potential-content">
            <div class="casted-content content" style="">
                <div><b>Casted Talent for Role</b></div>
                <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                    <li class="ui-state-default11 bob">Item 1</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default12">Item 2</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default13">Item 3</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default14">Item 4</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default15">Item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="potential-content content" style="">
                <div><b>Potential Talent for Role</b></div>
                <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">ffff
                    <li class="ui-state-default21">Item 21</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default22">Item 22</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default23">Item 23</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default25">Item 24</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default26">Item 25</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</DIV>
<DIV class="ui-layout-south" style="margin:0px !important;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7E6E2 !important;">
    <div class="rejected-content" style="padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7E6E2 !important;">
        <div><b>Rejected Talent for Role</b></div>
            <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default31">Item 31</li>
                <li class="ui-state-default32">Item 32</li>
                <li class="ui-state-default33">Item 33</li>
                <li class="ui-state-default34">Item 34</li>
                <li class="ui-state-default35">Item 35</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</DIV>
</BODY>
```

the Item's z-index and location in the dom needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think they work normally toghether.

Look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/trmr9/

Comment: Yeah this is close but in this example the visual won't drag accross the pane.  I just got it though... I'll post.

Comment: I think you were just missing this: helper: function (e, ui) { return $(ui.get(0)).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();},

Answer (score 0):

Using the connectWith option for your sortables will get what you want.

```
$('#firstList').sortable({connectWith : '#otherList'});
```

on one.

```
$('#otherList').sortable({connectWith : '#firstList'});
```

on the other.

It shouldn't make a difference if they're within different containing DIVs.

Comment: yeah it shouldn't make a difference if they're in different div's... the "pane" was just throwing the visual off.