# jquery ui layout plug-in and ui sortable - interchangeable lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-layout, jquery-ui-layout

Having the jquery ui layout plugin and two sortable lists elements drag/drop in only one direction. See example: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/droppable.html
Each list is in a different pane.

I can't make elements do drag/drop to either list regardless I set the property connectWith: "ul" to each sortable list.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. float:left directly applied to the

was messing all up.

Also found this post: [jquery sortable list accross different panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260660/jquery-sortable-list-accross-different-panes)